# Android Studio issue on Flutterwave payment

Tags: build

When I try to build the flutter app i get this message:

`Launching lib\main.dart on NTH NX9 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
lib/bloc/confirmbooking/payment_gateway.dart:256:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'style'.
style: FlutterwaveStyle(
^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutterwave_standard-1.0.8/lib/core/flutterwave.dart:28:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
Flutterwave(
^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1343
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9m
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1`

Here is My code:

```
class FlutterwavePayment {
  void makePayment({
    UserData? user,
    required String amount,
    required String publishKey,
    required String currency,
    required Function(ChargeResponse param) onSuccess,
    required Function(dynamic error) onError,
  }) async {
    final Customer customer = Customer(
        email: email,
        name: user?.fullname ?? AppLocalizations.of(Get.context!)!.unknown,
        phoneNumber: user?.identity ?? '');

    final Flutterwave flutterwave = Flutterwave(
      context: Get.context!,
      publicKey: publishKey,
      currency: currency,
      redirectUrl: 'https://facebook.com',
      txRef: const Uuid().v1(),
      amount: amount,
      customer: customer,
      paymentOptions: "card, payattitude, barter, bank transfer, ussd",
      customization: Customization(title: "Wallet Payment"),
      isTestMode: true,
      style: FlutterwaveStyle(
        buttonColor: ColorRes.themeColor,
        buttonTextStyle: kRegularTextStyle,
        appBarColor: ColorRes.smokeWhite,
        appBarTitleTextStyle: kBoldWhiteTextStyle.copyWith(
          color: ColorRes.charcoal,
        ),
      ),
    );
    flutterwave.charge().then((value) {
      if (value.success == true) {
        onSuccess(value);
      } else {
        onError(AppLocalizations.of(Get.context!)!.paymentFailed);
      }
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      onError(AppLocalizations.of(Get.context!)!.paymentFailed);
    });
  }
}
```